# Remove specific array element from JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have below array of Objects-

```
var myarray = [ { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "ADF12345", "terms": "1" }, { "id": "ABC12345", "AlphaNumber": "LL8888", "terms": "1" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "KK6666", "terms": "2" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "QQ1111", "terms": "3" }, { "id": "ABC12346", "AlphaNumber": "RR4444", "terms": "3" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "SS1111", "terms": "5" }, { "id": "ABC12347", "AlphaNumber": "ASQE223", "terms": "5" } ]
```

I want to check if multiple entries for the same terms are present in the array and remove the node that has id="" which means my output would have an entry having term and id not equals ''(empty string) for duplicate term entries.

Final value of myarray after the logic could be as below:

```
[{"id":"ABC12345","AlphaNumber":"LL8888","terms":"1"},{"id":"","AlphaNumber":"KK6666","terms":"2"},{"id":"ABC12346","AlphaNumber":"RR4444","terms":"3"},{"id":"ABC12347","AlphaNumber":"ASQE223","terms":"5"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `Array#reduce` and `Map`

1. Group your data by `terms` in a `Map`.
2. Find an item where `id` is not an `empty` string, if such an item does not exist pick the first item.

```js
const 
  myarray = [ { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "ADF12345", "terms": "1" }, { "id": "ABC12345", "AlphaNumber": "LL8888", "terms": "1" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "KK6666", "terms": "2" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "QQ1111", "terms": "3" }, { "id": "ABC12346", "AlphaNumber": "RR4444", "terms": "3" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "SS1111", "terms": "5" }, { "id": "ABC12347", "AlphaNumber": "ASQE223", "terms": "5" } ],
  
  res = Array.from(myarray.reduce(
    (m, o) => (m.has(o.terms) ? m.get(o.terms).push(o) : m.set(o.terms, [o]), m),
    new Map()
  ).values(), (v) => v.find(o => o.id !== "") || v[0]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `map` object with `terms` as key. If the current `terms` doesn't exist in `map` or the already existing object doesn't have `id`, use the current object

```js
const myarray = [ { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "ADF12345", "terms": "1" }, { "id": "ABC12345", "AlphaNumber": "LL8888", "terms": "1" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "KK6666", "terms": "2" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "QQ1111", "terms": "3" }, { "id": "ABC12346", "AlphaNumber": "RR4444", "terms": "3" }, { "id": "", "AlphaNumber": "SS1111", "terms": "5" }, { "id": "ABC12347", "AlphaNumber": "ASQE223", "terms": "5" } ]

const map = {};

for (const o of myarray) {
  if (!map[o.terms]?.id)
    map[o.terms] = o
}

console.log( Object.values(map) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 steps:

1. Group data by `terms`
2. Filter data when data in a group greater than 1 item. Otherwise, keep the data in the group which have only one item.

```
if(values.length > 1) values = values.filter(r => r.id !== "");
```

```js
const myarray=[{"id":"","AlphaNumber":"ADF12345","terms":"1"},{"id":"ABC12345","AlphaNumber":"LL8888","terms":"1"},{"id":"","AlphaNumber":"KK6666","terms":"2"},{"id":"","AlphaNumber":"QQ1111","terms":"3"},{"id":"ABC12346","AlphaNumber":"RR4444","terms":"3"},{"id":"","AlphaNumber":"SS1111","terms":"5"},{"id":"ABC12347","AlphaNumber":"ASQE223","terms":"5"}];
const result = [];

// Step 1
const groupingData = myarray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.terms] ??= [];
  acc[curr.terms].push(curr);
  return acc;
}, {});

// Step 2
for(let [key, values] of Object.entries(groupingData)){
  if(values.length > 1) values = values.filter(r => r.id !== "");
  result.push(values);
}
console.log(result.flat());
```

Comment: Two problems with your current solution: 1) If there are 2 items where `term` is same but `id` is empty for both, then resultant would not have any objects with this `term`.

Comment: 2) If there are 2 items where `term` is same and `id` is not empty for both, then resultant would have both objects with this `term`.

Comment: I don't think so. You can read the OP's requirement again and check my output answer

Comment: For OP's current input it works but for other inputs it might fail. Consider this input `[{ id: "", AlphaNumber: "ADF12345", terms: "1" }, { id: "", AlphaNumber: "LL8888", terms: "1" }]`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
const array = [{
    id: "",
    AlphaNumber: "ADF12345",
    terms: "1"
  }, {
    id: "ABC12345",
    AlphaNumber: "LL8888",
    terms: "1"
  }, {
    id: "",
    AlphaNumber: "KK6666",
    terms: "2"
  }, {
    id: "",
    AlphaNumber: "QQ1111",
    terms: "3"
  }, {
    id: "ABC12346",
    AlphaNumber: "RR4444",
    terms: "3"
  }, {
    id: "",
    AlphaNumber: "SS1111",
    terms: "5"
  }, {
    id: "ABC12347",
    AlphaNumber: "ASQE223",
    terms: "5"
  }],

  obj = {};

for (const o of array) obj[o.terms]?.id || (obj[o.terms] = o);
```

More about [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)